# Expedia API Cross Origin Requests

Tags: javascript, api, cors, same-origin-policy

I'm playing around with a hotel search frontend using the [Expedia API](http://developer.ean.com/docs/). I set up a node.js server running on localhost:3000 and a simple Backbone view for entering location and dates.

However when submitting the request to Expedia, I always get

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load ... http://localhost:3000 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Here is my submit code, which should work fine:

```
$.support.cors = true; // not really done at every request
var from = this.$el.find( "input[name=date-from_submit]" ).val(),
    to = this.$el.find( "input[name=date-to_submit]" ).val(),
    where = this.ui.place.val();

$.ajax({ 
    "url": "http://api.ean.com/ean-services/rs/hotel/v3/list?" + 
      "destinationString=" + where +
      "&cid=55505" + //test CID
      "&minorRev=20" +  
      "&arrivalDate=" + from + 
      "&departureDate=" + to +
      "&room1=2" + 
      "&apiKey=<apikey>",
    "dataType": "json",
    "accept": "application/json"
}).always( function( a, b, c ) {
    console.debug( a, b, c );
});
```

I tried this code from a JSFiddle to see if they only prohibit `localhost`, but no avail. Same Origin Policy error again.

Now I'm wondering:

1. Does Expedia support Cross Origin Requests at all?
2. Maybe I'm supposed to enter the Origin of my choice somewhere on their website? I didn't find anything.
3. If the answer to 1. is "No", then how are developers supposed to build a product with their API?
4. Am I just stupid?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The Expedia API documentation makes no mention of CORS support, so I'm assuming they don't support CORS. You could try asking on their support forums for additional guidance: https://support.ean.com/home In answer to how developers should build a product, you can still use their API, you just can't use it in pure Javascript.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. The request works when I do it from the node server, so I'll have to include some server logic as well.

Comment: @prayerslayer i know it's been awhile, but do you remember how'd you get around this issue? did Expedia ever get back to you?

Comment: @Xander No they didn’t. An easy, but not ideal solution is to proxy Expedia requests through your own backend.

Answer (score 1):

Use dataType:"jsonp"

```
$.ajax({
cors:true,
dataType:"jsonp",   
url:"API END POINT",
method:"GET",
success:function(data){
    console.log(data);
}

});
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Because the EAN API doesn't return JSONP, it returns JSON. A JSONP result is a JSON result wrapped in a function call. So this will never work with the Expedia API.

Comment: dataType:jsonp was working earlier with Expedia AJAX calls, but in recent days, it stopped working.